# how to track traffic across n domains with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

Example: I have 3 sites, a.com, b.com, and c.com. How can I keep track of the traffic that starts out at a.com and ends up at c.com, using Tag Manager and Universal Analytics?

I know that using referral source is an easy enough thing to view in UA, but I really need referral referral source because UA only uses the most recent referrer, not a referrer *n* sites back.

Please note that this question is not just about cross-domain tracking, rather keeping track of a site visited before the current referral.

Comment: You can set a JS cookie with the current URL in GTM using a Tag that fires when the Referrer doesn't match one of your other sites. Then set up a different Tag - one for each of your sites - which triggers when there's a different Referral to update the cookie AND to push a custom variable to GA, as suggested below by Eike.

Answer (score 1):

**Using GTM**

If you use GTM (Google Tag Manager), you must create a permanent variable that contains the domains where your site might go to or be visited from.

Lets call it "myDomains". It would be like this:
myDomains : permanent : "a.com,b.com,c.com" (without quotes)

[image]

After this, in your pageViews tags, you'll need to set some fields:
In "more configurations", go to "fields to set" add some fields and set the following properties:

> Field Name : Value
>
> allowLinker : true

And, if you use multiple sub-domains, add the following:

> cookieDomain : auto

[image]

Now, still in the "more configurations", under "Cross Domain Tracking", you will use the variable myDomains (that we created before) on the "Auto Link Domains" as this:

> {{myDomains}}

Now you just have to save it and now you can track your multiple domains.

---

**Hard-Coded**

If You don't use GTM and insert the tags directly to your source code, then what you need is similar to what we did in GTM:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com'] );
```

Note that just like we did in GTM, we:

- set the cookieDomain (implicitaly with "auto")
- set the field "allowLinker" true
- set the "autoLink" to an array of strings, each one containing one of the domains that will send/receive visitors to/from your site.

*Note: if you use the same domain but just diferent levels of sub-domains, you will just need to set the **cookieDomain** to **auto**, no need for Cross-Domain.*

---

**Further reading**

[Google guide for this implementation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en#GTM)

Comment: I am currently doing the well-described steps here. However, I don't think these steps alone will let me see the following in Analytics:
_a visitor started out at a.com, went directly to b.com, then went directly to c.com_

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to do this within the GA interface.

What you could do is create a new GA property that all these websites send data to (if you haven't already done so).

Then create a filter for this property that appends the hostname to the request URI. You can learn to so this [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) in the Google documentation. This will allow you to see the full URL thus allowing you see all websites.

I would then create two custom dimensions: `sessionId` and `hitTimeStamp`. These can deployed through Google Tag Manager. An article by Simo Ahava found [here](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/) explains well how to do this.

Using SQL, you will be able to partition `page` by `sessionID` and order by `hitTimeStamp` to give you a view on page flow across each website to c.com.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your use case, but you can catch the original referrer, store it somewhere (e.g. in a cookie) and then send it e.g. via the url to the following page. Then you catch the query parameter and use it in a set call:

```
ga('set', 'referrer', '<original referrer>');
ga('send','pageview');
```

For all hits following the set call GA will record the referrer as the value of ">" which you replace with your captured value.

Comment: I think this the right approach, but I'm a little unclear how this would look in analytics. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no, that was a wrong answer - I misread your sentence regarding cross-domain tracking (thought you did not want to use that). Since you have implemented cross-domain tracking already GA should keep the original referrer in any case, no manual intervention necessary, provided you have added all your domains to the referral exclusion list (if you have not then you cross domain tracking is broken).  Then create a sequence type segment with "1st step hostname eq. domainA", "2nd step hostname eq. domainB" and "3rd step hostname eq. domainC" to see who has traversed your domain in that order.

Comment: It sounds like sequence segments are about to make my day (along with this answer of course). One thing I'm confused about - in Tag Manager, should the exclusion list be a custom JS variable, like this http://jsbin.com/vamulizefe/edit?js or a constant with the sites to include listed out?

Comment: Referral exclusion list is a part of the property settings in Google Analytics (in the "tracking code" section if the menu). Simply add all domains that are part of you cross domain tracking setup, then those will be ignored as traffic sources and the original traffic source or referrer will be maintained throughout.

Comment: I was doing this in tag manager with the code in my last reply (assuming it works correctly).

Will you post the sequential segments comment as an answer?